# Integration of $\int e^{\sin^2(x)+ \cos^2(x)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus

> Calculate the indefinite integral
>   $$\int e^{\sin^2(x)+ \cos^2(x)}\,dx.$$

Not sure how to do this

Comment: It is an indefinite integral.

Comment: Here's a similarly difficult one: $$\int e^{\ln(x^n)}dx$$

Comment: $$\int e^{ln(x^n)}\,dx $$ =$$\int (x^n)\,dx $$

Comment: $$\frac{x^{(n+1)}}{n+1} +C$$ just like the power rule on a intergral that would be the integral result right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's not hard at all.  $$\int e^{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}\,dx=  \int e^1\,dx,$$ since $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$. So $e^1$ is a constant and you can pull this out of the integral. which will leave you with $e\int\,dx$, which is just $ex+C$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**: $$\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$$ so therefore
$$e^{\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)} = ....?$$